# excludeDevtools seems to have no effect under Spring Boot 1.5.1.RELEASE (but OK in 1.4.4.RELEASE)

Tags: spring-boot

I've created a fresh new Spring Boot 1.5.1.RELEASE project with a devtools dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

When running from inside Idea this works no problem.  However, after performing a bootRepackage, the resulting fat jar has no devtools jar in its lib folder.  I have the following entry in build.gradle:

```
bootRepackage {     
    mainClass = 'com.example.HotreloadApplication'
    excludeDevtools = false 
}
```

And upon a ./gradlew bootRepackage and a java -jar build/libs/hotreload-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar, I can see that it fires up without devtools still.  Upon opening the jar, I can also see that it is not included.

When moving springBootVersion back to '1.4.4.RELEASE' howeverm everything works absolutely as expected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  I've included the entirety of my build.gradle following this message.

Many thanks,
Duncan

----- build.gradle ----

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'hotreload'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}

bootRepackage {
    mainClass = 'com.example.HotreloadApplication'
    excludeDevtools = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is superseded by [this issue on the Spring Boot tracker](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8308) that the author has cross-posted.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct, thanks Stephane.  A workaround is posted on the github ticket, by adding the following block to build.gradle:

```
springBoot {
    excludeDevtools = false
}
```

With any luck, this bug should be fixed in 1.5.2.

Many thanks,
Duncan